# Issue warning on the closing of a modal and ask users to confirm before close

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, modal-dialog, user-experience

I'm trying to implement angularjs modals and doing validations currently. I don't want modal to close when people click outside of the modal window. The reason for that is my modals are kind of heavy in functionality and if by mistake it happens, they will lose huge amount of work done on modal window.

I could allow them to close on clicking outside or pressing esc but I still need to issue a warning saying that they could lose the work. And modal will only close if they choose to do so. The same behavior needs to be replicated while clicking on cancel button. I don't have to prevent users from closing the modal on esc or clicking outside if there was a mechanism to issue a warning. Currently I could use "static: true" on modal to prevent the closing of a modal on clicking outside, but "keyboard: false" doesn't seem to work. It still closes when I press "esc". To summarize, two problems:
1. how do I issue a warning that they are about the lose the work on clicking cancel, pressing escape, or clicking outside?
2. why does 'keyboard: false' not work?

Here is `the` http://plnkr.co/edit/8ueIf3KXO5ozXEclJBRe?p=preview with 'keyboard: false' not working? You could modify the same plunker for 1st problem as well.

Maybe I'm over-thinking this. I've been struggling on the usability flow of my app and the reason for making this modal is that the overall flow is kind of complex and it gets really confusing if I don't use modals.

It is something like I'm trying to configure data for an university so first I have to configure university, then schools, then their departments, and finally in each department, there could be teachers, assets, classes, etc. Say this is kind of one time set up when university buys this app and after one time setup is done, they will rarely change this information.

While doing one time setup, for each assets there could CRUD operation involved and each of these operation could result in up to four new screens.

To simplify the process, I'm trying to implement CRUD operations using modals so that while setting up user is clear on what they are working on university(CRUD)-->school(CRUD)-->dept(CRUD)-->class(CRUD)-->teacher(CRUD). How do you guys deal with such hierarchical data setup and how do you simplify the usability? Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It's `keyboard: false` NOT `keyboard: 'false'` :)

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you for spotting that. :)